# Searching a specific project sub-directory with projectile

Tags: projectile, counsel

I recently found Projectile and I am loving it. I really like the ivy/counsel integration as well. One thing is missing though:

I am working on a *huge* project of hundreds of files. This is stored in one big massive Git repository which projectile recognizes as the root of the project. I'd like to keep it recognizing this as the root, as there are some dependencies across the various folders.

How can I run projectile search (e.g. `C-c p s r` for using ripgrep) and limit results to a specific sub-directory in that project?

#### Update 2020-06-17

I just found the `--iglob` option for `ripgrep`. I'll keep looking for a way to use this along with `counsel-projectile-rg`, but if anyone knows I'd love to hear an answer!

Comment: hundreds == "Huge" ;-)  I just counted the number of files in our project: 68921.

Comment: @Tobias Oh gosh. *That* is huge. … I just checked and this project too has a few thousand files. A lot of those are build artifacts; narrowing the scope of the search yields about 1300 files. Whatever it is, +100 is a lot of search results to come through. :)

Comment: Maybe, [elgrep](https://github.com/TobiasZawada/elgrep) can help you. You can give regexp for the directories and files you want to search. Furthermore, you have multiple search criteria for each file. You can even split each file into search records. That should allow you to narrow the hits.

Comment: For your case I do use `rg.el` which ask about where to search and and some other options. Also use counsel and a few others tool wrappers as convenience.

Comment: Note that `helm-do-ag` as mentioned in this answer seems to work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982412/projectile-search-only-part-of-the-project

Answer (score 2):

You can also try `C-u M-x project-find-regexp`.

It's a part of the `project` package, built-in in the latest versions of Emacs but also distributed through GNU ELPA.

Be warned though: this calling convention doesn't honor the `.gitignore` entries (only ignores standard "junk" files and utility directories). So if you have a lot of files in the subdirectory as well, it could take a while.